# How do you deploy a form linked with PHP to a MySQL Database to Heroku

Tags: forms, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, cleardb

Long story short I have a form made in HTML/CSS that is being processed with PHP to populate a MySQL Database. We then have another form that is going to be used as a search for the same DB which will then show a search results page. How do we package this and then deploy the entire "app" since the front end is not a web application but more of a static website.

Comment: by deploy do you mean publish to the web? Is there anything wrong with your form?

Comment: we want to host the entire thing on heroku, so deploy the whole root folder to heroku that encompasses the DB and the forms and so that each forum has its own extension of the domain